# Change serializer format for SignalR?

Tags: .net, signalr, serialization

Is it possible to change the serializer provider and also the format for SignalR?
In default it is JSON format.
It is possible to change the format to BSON?

Thanks for your answer!

Bye,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SignalR wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility) offers a way to replace the default serializer with your own IJsonSerializer. The stated goal for this functionality is to change how dates and the like are serialized.

I suggest asking yourself whether you really need the BSON formatting. If you're worried about bandwidth or transmission time, I suggest benchmarking first and changing later. I spend most of my time at work sending big, complex objects over the wire and C# and have never had a problem with speed.